# Transfer data between fragments with pagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

Current Replaced fragment.

```
public class SlidingTabsFragment extends Fragment {

private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

public SlidingTabsFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Context context= getActivity();
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new Harkayin_PagerAdapter(fm,context));

    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}



 ...
```

Here is PagerAdapter, which holds three sliding pages with same fragment /Fragment_Hashvehamarner();/

```
public class Harkayin_PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public Harkayin_PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() { return 3;}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String[] tabs= mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hashvehamar_tabs);
    return tabs[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment_Hashvehamarner();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment_Hashvehamarner();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment_Hashvehamarner();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null){
        return fragment;
    }else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("Harkayin_PagerAdapter", "Error in creating fragment");
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the page holder fragment

```
public class Fragment_Hashvehamarner  extends Fragment {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
HashMap<String, List<String[]>> listDataChild;
ArrayList<String[]> listHeaderData;
View rootView;

public Fragment_Hashvehamarner() {}

...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hashvayin_plan, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(rootView.getContext(), listHeaderData,
            listDataChild);
    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


private void prepareListData() {

    DataAdapter mDbHelper = new DataAdapter(rootView.getContext());
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    listHeaderData = new ArrayList<String[]>(mDbHelper.getHashvehamarHeader(1));
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>(mDbHelper.getHashvehamarChildData(1));
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

Now the question: how to get current page position from PageAdapter into current page holder fragment /Fragment_Hashvehamarner()/.

Comment: `how to get current page position from PageAdapter into current page holder fragment` can you explain it further

Comment: There are three sliding pages, each of them shows the same fragment /Fragment_Hashvehamarner()/. Each page when i am sliding has int position, I want to get that position into fragment when fragment creates.

Comment: I want to know which page is loading, first position 0, second position 1 or third position 3, to getting data from database.

Answer (score 1):

add below method to your `Fragment_Hashvehamarner` class.

```
public static final String EXTRA_PAGE_POSITION = "page.position";

public static Fragment_Hashvehamarner newInstance(int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(EXTRA_PAGE_POSITION, id);
        Fragment_Hashvehamarner fragment = new Fragment_Hashvehamarner();
        fragment.setArguments(args);        
        return fragment;
    }
```

and in `onCreate` method of `Fragment_Hashvehamarner`:

```
int mSelectedPosition= getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_PAGE_POSITION);
```

then in your adapter:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = Fragment_Hashvehamarner.newInstance(position);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: mSelectedPosition is String. Log.i("Fragment", "Hashvehamarner onCreate ---"+mSelectedPosition); --> I/Fragment﹕ Hashvehamarner onCreate ---null

Comment: sorry it is a typo it must be `int mSelectedPosition= getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_PAGE_POSITION);`

Comment: On the first page mSelectedPosition = 1 /good/, when I am sliding to second page mSelectedPosition = 2/perfect/, when I am sliding to third page onCreate method didn't work, after I am sliding back to the second page  mSelectedPosition = 0,

Comment: this is because of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. this adapter store your three fragment, so when you are on page for example 25 it stores in memory page26 and 24 and when you go back to page 24 it delete page 26 and create page 23 so now in memory you have 23,24,25 and in your case because page 3 is the last it just delete page0 from memory then when you back to page2 it create page0 and now you have 3 pages in memory 1,2,3 you can read docs and set off screen loading by `setOfScreenLoading();` to tell how many pages it must keep in memory.